# Some of the page numbers are repeated when exporting to word

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report with 50 pages. I have one list control, and this list control contains a table control. I am using grouping in the list, with a page break at the end. I want each group on one page. For example, if the size of my data is bit more for some of the pages then it moves to the second page.

The problem is I am getting some of the pages with the same number where data for one group is more than one page. I am using this expression in the footer:

```
format(Globals!PageNumber & "of" & Globals!TotalPages)
```

When I have 50 pages then after exporting to Word I will get 45, becuase 5 or 6 pages will be repeated, giving "1 of 45" instead of "1 of 50".

Note that I am using SSRS 2005.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question but recently ran into this issue myself so it might help someone else.

There are a lot of examples out there that use casting in the examples for the page number display (CStr or ToString()). Whenever I invoked those methods, the counts would be off when exporting to Word (either doc or docx).

The only way I could get it to work is with three separate text boxes in the footer with these expressions:

```
=Globals!PageNumber
"of"
=Globals!TotalPages
```

Avoid the use of those other approaches (including the wrapping Format function -- I don't think that's doing anything). Three separate text boxes was the only way I could get this to work.